# How to get localized name of System Folder in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to get localized name of System Folders according to user's language settings.
For example, "Documents" directory is displayed "Documentos" in Spanish, "書類" in Japanese.

Is there any way to get these localized folder name programmatically?
I'm using Cocoa framework on OSX 10.6 and 10.7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into this [method on NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/displayNameAtPath:):

```
- (NSString *)displayNameAtPath:(NSString *)path
```